# SQL query running slow due to date functions

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression, query-performance

I'm running a query using Management Studio 18 against SQL server database and it's taking 3-4 minutes to run on the server. If I remove the dates functions then it runs in 1 minute on my machine but I need the dates function. Will anyone be able to help? Thank you in advance!

Here is the original query which takes 3-4 on the server:

```
With A AS 
(
Select          DSS.transactionSynchronizationId, DSS.transactionDate, DSS.transactionTime,
                convert (varchar, CAST(DateAdd(minute, DateDiff(minute, 0, DSS.transactionTime), 0) AS smalldatetime), 24) As DSS_TransactionTime_EST, DSS.processedBy, 
                DSS.transactionType, DSS.country, DSS.state, DSS.partner,
                DSS.originUnitPrice, DSS.discount, DSS.taxAmount, 
                Case When transactionType In ('REFUND', 'CHARGEBACK', 'CREDIT') Then (DSS.taxAmount*-1) Else DSS.taxAmount End As DSS_Tax_Amount,
                Case When DSS.country In ('US', 'PR', 'CA') And transactionType In ('REFUND', 'CHARGEBACK', 'CREDIT') Then -DSS.originUnitPrice - DSS.discount 
                When DSS.country In ('US', 'PR', 'CA') And transactionType Not In ('REFUND', 'CHARGEBACK', 'CREDIT') Then DSS.originUnitPrice - DSS.discount
                When DSS.country Not In ('US', 'PR', 'CA') And transactionType In ('REFUND', 'CHARGEBACK', 'CREDIT') Then (-DSS.originUnitPrice - DSS.discount - DSS.taxAmount)
                Else DSS.originUnitPrice - DSS.discount - DSS.taxAmount End AS DSS_Gross_Sales
From TableA As DSS
),
C As
(
Select Distinct VTX.[Transaction Synchronization ID], VTX.[Transaction Process Date], VTX.[Transaction Process Time],
                convert(varchar, DATEADD (HOUR , -5 , [Transaction Process Time]) , 24) As Vertex_TransactionTime_EST, VTX.[Situs Country Code 2], VTX.[Situs Main Division],
                VTX.[Taxpayer Division Code], VTX.[Gross Amount] As VTX_Gross_Amount, Sum (VTX.[Tax Amount]) As VTX_Tax_Amount 
From TableB As VTX

Group By VTX.[Transaction Synchronization ID], VTX.[Transaction Process Date], VTX.[Transaction Process Time], VTX.[Situs Country Code 2], VTX.[Situs Main Division],
                VTX.[Taxpayer Division Code], VTX.[Gross Amount]
),
B As
(
Select          C.[Transaction Synchronization ID], C.[Transaction Process Date], C.[Transaction Process Time],
                convert(varchar, DATEADD (HOUR , -5 , C.[Transaction Process Time]) , 24) As Vertex_TransactionTime_EST, C.[Situs Country Code 2], C.[Situs Main Division],
                C.[Taxpayer Division Code], Sum (C.VTX_Gross_Amount) As VTX_Gross_Amount, Sum (C.VTX_Tax_Amount) As VTX_Tax_Amount 
From C

Group By C.[Transaction Synchronization ID], C.[Transaction Process Date], C.[Transaction Process Time],
                convert(varchar, DATEADD (HOUR , -5 , C.[Transaction Process Time]) , 24), C.[Situs Country Code 2], C.[Situs Main Division],
                C.[Taxpayer Division Code]
)
Select          A.transactionSynchronizationId, B.[Transaction Process Date], B.Vertex_TransactionTime_EST, A.transactionDate, A.DSS_TransactionTime_EST, A.processedBy, A.transactionType,
                B.[Situs Country Code 2], A.country, B.[Situs Main Division], A.state, A.partner, B.[Taxpayer Division Code], B.VTX_Gross_Amount, B.VTX_Tax_Amount, A.originUnitPrice,
                A.discount, A.DSS_Tax_Amount, A.DSS_Gross_Sales, Cast ((A.DSS_Gross_Sales - B.VTX_Gross_Amount) As decimal (10,2)) As 'Gross Sales Diff', 
                A.DSS_Tax_Amount, Cast (A.DSS_Tax_Amount - B.VTX_Tax_Amount As decimal (10,2)) As 'Tax Diff'
From A Join B
On A.transactionSynchronizationId = B.[Transaction Synchronization ID]
```

Here is the query which runs faster:

```
With A AS 
(
Select          DSS.transactionSynchronizationId, DSS.transactionDate, DSS.transactionTime,
                convert (varchar, CAST(DateAdd(minute, DateDiff(minute, 0, DSS.transactionTime), 0) AS smalldatetime), 24) As DSS_TransactionTime_EST, DSS.processedBy, 
                DSS.transactionType, DSS.country, DSS.state, DSS.partner,
                DSS.originUnitPrice, DSS.discount, DSS.taxAmount, 
                Case When transactionType In ('REFUND', 'CHARGEBACK', 'CREDIT') Then (DSS.taxAmount*-1) Else DSS.taxAmount End As DSS_Tax_Amount,
                Case When DSS.country In ('US', 'PR', 'CA') And transactionType In ('REFUND', 'CHARGEBACK', 'CREDIT') Then -DSS.originUnitPrice - DSS.discount 
                When DSS.country In ('US', 'PR', 'CA') And transactionType Not In ('REFUND', 'CHARGEBACK', 'CREDIT') Then DSS.originUnitPrice - DSS.discount
                When DSS.country Not In ('US', 'PR', 'CA') And transactionType In ('REFUND', 'CHARGEBACK', 'CREDIT') Then (-DSS.originUnitPrice - DSS.discount - DSS.taxAmount)
                Else DSS.originUnitPrice - DSS.discount - DSS.taxAmount End AS DSS_Gross_Sales
From TableA As DSS
),
C As
(
Select Distinct VTX.[Transaction Synchronization ID], VTX.[Transaction Process Date], VTX.[Transaction Process Time],
                convert(varchar, DATEADD (HOUR , -5 , [Transaction Process Time]) , 24) As Vertex_TransactionTime_EST, VTX.[Situs Country Code 2], VTX.[Situs Main Division],
                VTX.[Taxpayer Division Code], VTX.[Gross Amount] As VTX_Gross_Amount, Sum (VTX.[Tax Amount]) As VTX_Tax_Amount 
From TableB As VTX

Group By VTX.[Transaction Synchronization ID], VTX.[Transaction Process Date], VTX.[Transaction Process Time], VTX.[Situs Country Code 2], VTX.[Situs Main Division],
                VTX.[Taxpayer Division Code], VTX.[Gross Amount]
),
B As
(
Select          C.[Transaction Synchronization ID], C.[Transaction Process Date], C.[Transaction Process Time],
                 C.[Situs Country Code 2], C.[Situs Main Division],
                C.[Taxpayer Division Code], Sum (C.VTX_Gross_Amount) As VTX_Gross_Amount, Sum (C.VTX_Tax_Amount) As VTX_Tax_Amount 
From C

Group By C.[Transaction Synchronization ID], C.[Transaction Process Date], C.[Transaction Process Time],
                  C.[Situs Country Code 2], C.[Situs Main Division],
                C.[Taxpayer Division Code]
)
Select          A.transactionSynchronizationId, B.[Transaction Process Date], A.transactionDate, A.DSS_TransactionTime_EST, A.processedBy, A.transactionType,
                B.[Situs Country Code 2], A.country, B.[Situs Main Division], A.state, A.partner, B.[Taxpayer Division Code], B.VTX_Gross_Amount, B.VTX_Tax_Amount, A.originUnitPrice,
                A.discount, A.DSS_Tax_Amount, A.DSS_Gross_Sales, 
                A.DSS_Tax_Amount, Cast (A.DSS_Tax_Amount - B.VTX_Tax_Amount As decimal (10,2)) As 'Tax Diff'
From A Join B
On A.transactionSynchronizationId = B.[Transaction Synchronization ID]
```

Comment: These queries are extremely difficult to read. Maybe try to eliminate the portions that are not pertinent to the question and present a more simple query for us to look at. But if you don't need the date functions inside the CTE for a join/where-clause, pull them out into the select statement that returns the actual data.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server is it running?

Comment: What are you hoping to get from `B` that you don't from `C`? `B` aggregate the columns of `C` adding an extra column with the date calculation that gets the `[Transaction Process Time]` to the nearest second but the rows are still aggregated by  `[Transaction Process Time]` so the `SUM`s will still be the same...

Answer (score 0):

Things to do so:

- simplify your queries, surely there must be a way ? There seems to be aggregation redundancy...
- run the **execution plan** and find out where the bottleneck is
- try running each block separately, you might find out that one is taking significantly more time than others
- show your table structure including **indexes** and some sample data, it's likely the query optimizer is not able to take advantage of indexes for that query
- improve the **naming conventions**: table names aliases such as A, B, C are not meaningful, it's not immediately clear what they represent and the risk of confusion is higher
- if the query is part of a stored procedure:

  - sometimes you can use variables instead of elaborate expressions (for values that need calculating only once)
  - use temporary tables, and fill them in multiple steps - trying to come up with a single CTE may result in less performance
- perhaps you could also **filter out the source tables** with `WHERE` clauses, it's hard to tell without knowing the data and purpose, but I have the impression that you are pulling all the data to then aggregate it.

Yes, this is pretty hard to read for us, and probably for you as well.

My immediate recommendation is to start with the first building block, make sure that your query is optimized, uses indexes whenever possible, and does not fetch more data than necessary. Always look at the execution plan. If necessary, add indexes, for example on the dates if you are searching by date range. Even one minute is not acceptable response time. This can only increase as your datasets grow over time.

Now if you think that the problems come from statements like:

```
convert(varchar, DATEADD (HOUR , -5 , C.[Transaction Process Time]) , 24) As Vertex_TransactionTime_EST,
```

If you really must have this, perhaps try different forms, get rid of the varchar conversion. You are only returning `HH:mm:ss` with a time zone offset.

Speaking of which, I though I'd mention that SQL Server has time zone functions, for example [TODATETIMEOFFSET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/todatetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2014) or [AT TIME ZONE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) - it's good to know they exist.